# rename files in a folder with left pad zeros

Tags: batch-file

I need to rename multiple files in a folder. File names are either 6 digits long or 9 digits long and I need to left pad all the file names with leading zeros to make it a total of 16 digits long.

For example if the file name is `123456.jpg` then it should be renamed to `0000000000123456.jpg` and if it is `123456789.jpg` then it should be renamed to `0000000123456789.jpg`.

Maximum length of total digits should be always 16 digits.

There can be 100 or more files in the folder.

I tried something like this, which I know is not the code required for this task. But I started with this one and need help to move forward.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
rem iterate over all JPG files:
for %%f in (C:\Documents\Pictures\pic\*.jpg) do (
    rem store file name without extension
    set FileName=%%~nf
    rem Add leading zeroes:
    set FileName=00000000000!FileName!
    rem Add extension again
    set FileName=!FileName!%%~xf
    rem Rename the file
    rename "%%f" "!FileName!"
)
```

I would prefer a batch script. But if that is not possible, a VB script will be also accepted.

Based upon Stephan's recommendation, I have updated the code which is as below. However this code does not prefix any zeros to the file name `123456.jpg`.

I want to add here that my knowledge on batch script coding is very limited. The code I am trying is just the initial trial, but what I want and has also been mentioned in the question is that script should be able to prepad zeros irrespective of the file name is 6 digits long or 9 digits long and make it a total of 16 digits long. I think that even if the code I am trying starts to work, I would still not get what I am looking for.

When I run this code then it does not do anything.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
rem iterate over all JPG files:
for %%f in (C:\Documents\Pictures\pic\*.jpg) do (
    rem store file name without extension
    set FileName=%%~nf
    rem Add leading zeroes:
    set FileName=0000000000!FileName!
    set FileName=!FileName:~-16!
    rem Rename the file
    rename "%%f" "!FileName!"
    set FileName=!FileName!%%~xf
    rem Rename the file
    rename "%%f" "!FileName!"
)
```

Updated code which is converting 6 digits long file name to 16 digits long:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
rem iterate over all JPG files:
for %%f in (C:\Documents\Pictures\pic\*.jpg) do (
    rem store file name without extension
    set FileName=%%~nf
    rem Add leading zeroes:
    set FileName=000000000!FileName!
    set FileName=!FileName:~-16!
    set FileName=!FileName!%%~xf
    rem Rename the file
    rename "%%f" "!FileName!"
)
```

Comment: you add the zeros, but you don't cut for 16 characters afterwards. `set FileName=output_!FileName:~-16!%%~xf` should do (instead of your last `set` line).

Comment: The description and your code do not comply! you do not mention the `output_` prefix which your code tries to keep; so please update your post accordingly...

Comment: @aschipfl  I have just updated my code. Sorry for this

Comment: @Stephan I have added your recommendation in my code and updated it but it still does not work

Comment: "does not work" - could you please be more specific? We can't see your screen, you know? Two errors (typos?) in your code: a missing exclamation mark after `~16` and a missing closing paranthese at the end of the code. (and you missed the file extension now)

Comment: Please do not implement Stephan's solution in the code in your question; otherwise this thread does not make any sense at all...

Comment: @Stephan I have updated my code. However, i did not get where I am missing the file extension. I apologize but I could not find it. The only
place where file name is mentioned in the path and it has a file extension .jpg

Comment: It doesn't do anything, because of the (still) missing `)`. When the `for` loop gets parsed, the parser hits the end of file before finishing. With your last edit, you included the extension again (`%%~xf` - was missing in your last version) - but you should remove your first `ren`...

Comment: @Stephan. Thanks I got some success and I have updated the code in my post. However, this code converts 6 digits long file to 16 digits but how should I use some condition in my code so that when file name 6 digits long then it prefixes 10 zeros to it and when it is 9 digits long then it prefixes 7 zeros. The folder can have a mix of 6 digits long and 9 digits long file names.

Comment: *facepalm* !FileName:~-16! takes the _last 16 chars of the string_. Just be sure to add enough zeros before (I suggest sixteen - just to be sure)

Comment: Thanks @Stephan that worked great. Appreciate your help

Comment: I put the relevant information into an answer (I think the rest were just typos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of worrying about the initial length of the filename, just add enough zeros to the front of the filename and cut the resulting string to sixteen characters:

```
...
set FileName=%%~nf
set FileName=0000000000000000!FileName!
set FileName=!FileName:~-16!%%~xf
...
```